# What are these "modified" questions with no visible changes?

Tags: discussion

When looking at the questions list sorted by "active", I noticed a handful of older questions that popped up as modified. Usually when this happens it's a mod editing something, but these all showed as modified by 1 rep users. I clicked the questions to browse through the answers, comments, and edits, but saw no activity from the usernames stated on the question list. What's going on here?  Am I just blind?

[Why energy saving bulb flashes when the switch is off?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11798/why-energy-saving-bulb-flashes-when-the-switch-is-off)

[How much cooling can I expect from a central air conditioner?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/895/how-much-cooling-can-i-expect-from-a-central-air-conditioner)

[Can I put rigid foam on studs to prevent thermal bridging?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/15328/can-i-put-rigid-foam-on-studs-to-prevent-thermal-bridging)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason, today there have been a lot of 1-rep users posting follow-on questions as answers. I've been deleting the posts as soon as I see them, and as appropriate, leaving a comment for the user to post a new question.

You need 10k rep in order to see other peoples' deleted posts, which is why you can't see any visible changes.

---

See also: [Why does "Community" regularly bring very old topics back up to the top](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/949/why-does-community-regularly-bring-very-old-topics-back-up-to-the-top)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!