# Is there a timing to how often questions are posted?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that as a new question is posted the previous one  has an elapsed time (as do everyone before) that indicates how long it's been active. I've also noticed that sometimes questions are posted regularly by the hour, but others won't appear for several hours. Is this due to the amount of questions being posed? Or to an administrators' scheduling difficulty?

Comment: Related: http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/949/why-does-community-regularly-bring-very-old-topics-back-up-to-the-top

Comment: I was more curious as to the actual time interval (if any) for each new post and if there is a schedule that is followed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The home page is updated as soon as any questions or answers are posted, and when they — or any answers they have — are edited. There is no schedule for this, and no administrator involvement.

Also, as I explained in the Q&A [Why does "Community" regularly bring very old topics back up to the top](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/949/why-does-community-regularly-bring-very-old-topics-back-up-to-the-top) that there's an automated process that regularly bumps [unanswered questions](https://diy.stackexchange.com/unanswered) to the home page.

The timestamp that you see on the home page is rounded, so even if you see "1 hour ago" on several of them, it doesn't mean that they were all bumped at exactly the same time.

For example, I just took a snapshot of the home page:

[image]

The three "1 hour ago" links have timestamps of 14:31:00Z, 14:25:50Z and 14:23:10Z in order from top to bottom. You can see the actual time by hovering over the link.